# how to remove a total value in highchart

Tags: jquery, highcharts

This code html table :

```
<table id="data-highcart"><tr><td>Buah</td><td>Nilai</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Jeruk</td><td>2</td></tr>
      <tr><td>Mangga</td><td>5</td></tr>
       <tr><td>Total</td><td>7</td></tr></table>
```

how the total in the table does not appear in highchart ?,

PLease Help Me ,,

this code highchart me ,

```
$("#data-highcart").highcharts({

    data: {
        table: document.getElementById(table),
        startColumn: 0,
        endColumn: 1
    },
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: "Statistik"
    },
    yAxis: {
        allowDecimals: false,
        title: {
            text: textColom
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function() {
            return '<b>'+ this.series.name +'</b><br/>'+
                this.point.y +' '+ this.point.name.toLowerCase();
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the total is always the bottom row, you could exclude it using the [`endRow` option](http://code.highcharts.com/modules/data.src.js).

It does the following:

```
* - endRow : Integer
* In tabular input data, the last row (indexed by 0) to use. Defaults to the last row
* containing data.
```

In your simple example that would mean adding:

```
data: {
    endRow: 2
}
```

For more advanced cases you can use javascript to count and insert it that way:

```
data: {
    endRow: $('#data-highcart tr').length-2
}
```

See [this JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/zwLqgmx3/) if anything is unclear.